# django modelserializer merge

Tags: django, django-models, django-serializer

Using django2.0.2 ptyhon3.4

```
MySerializer.py
class post(serializers.ModelSerializer)
    class Meta:
        model = post
        fields = ("postuid","useruid","content")

class reply(serializers.ModelSerializer)
    class Meta:
        model = reply
        fields = ("replyuid","postuid","useruid","content")

class postview(serializers.ModelSerializer)
    reply = reply()
    post  = post()
    fields = ('reply','post')???
```

i want like this form

`{"postview":{"post":{postfield},"reply":[{replyfield}]}`

how to this

postview is not modelserializer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `serializers.Serializer` class instead:

```
class postview(serializers.Serializer):
    reply = reply(many=True)
    post  = post()
```

Note with `Serializer` base class you don't need `Meta` options. Just add as many fields as you need as serializer's attribute.

You can use `many=True` attribute to specify that `reply` contains list of objects.

Comment: I think, `reply = reply(many=True)` is better, coz he needs `list of dict` as result of `reply` attribute, right?